# `PlistBuddy` で `Add` すると，`Unrecognized Type: /` が返ってきてしまう

Tags: macos

osx の im，`JapaneseIM` の設定を `PlistBuddy` コマンドを使って行おうと考えているのですが，  
`Unrecognized Type` と謳われて，どうもうまく行きません．

実際に走らせている処理は以下です．

```
% pb=/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy  
% plistis=/System/Library/Input\ Methods/JapaneseIM.app/Contents/Resources/KeySetting_Default.plist  
% sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''/\'':character '/'" "${plistis}"  
Password:  
Unrecognized Type: /
```

やり方を思いつく限り試してみたのですが，どうしても上手くいきません．

そして，それがどうしてかよく分からないのですが，`Add` ではなく，`Set` を使うと問題なく処理を行ってくれるのです．

ちなみに `Set` のケースは，  
一度，直接 plist を編集したうえで試してます．

試した環境です．

```
% sw_vers  
ProductName:    Mac OS X  
ProductVersion: 10.10.2  
BuildVersion:   14C109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add`する場合はその値の型を指定する必要があります。（スラッシュ`'/'`を入れようとしてるのだから文字列に決まってるのですが、コマンドはそれを理解してくれません）

なので上記のコマンドに型の指定`string`を加えると下記のようになります。

```
% sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''/\'':character string '/'" "${plistis}"
```

`Set`の場合に同じ問題が起こらないのは、`Set`の場合は既存の値の入れ替えになるので、そこに入る値の型はあらかじめ決まっているからです。

Comment: なるほど，改めてマニュアル見直したら，しっかり書いてましたね．何度も目を通してはいたのですが...恥ずかしい限りです．

バックスラッシュ <code>\</code> についても同様のことをやりたかったので，当該スクリプトは以下のようになりました．

    # slash (solidus)g
    sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''/\'':character string '/'" "${plistis}"g
    # backslash (reverse solidus)g
    sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''\\\\\'':character string '\\\'" "${plistis}"

バックスラッシュの方は少々躓いて，結果なんとも見苦しい感じになってしまってますが :-p
この度は大変勉強になりました．

Comment: コメントがきたなくなってしまいました。すみません。バックスラッシュもやりたかったので，`sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''/\'':character string '/'" "${plistis}"` に加え，`sudo "${pb}" -c "Add :keys:before_typing:\''\\\\\'':character string '\\\'" "${plistis}"` も加えました，というお話でした．失礼いたしました．